# Get efi return code in uefi mode

Tags: shell, uefi

I boot into uefi mode And I have a xxx.efi, I would like to get it's return code I write a startup.sh to launch the xxx.efi How could I get the xxx.efi return code? I try like this, but it will return unknow flag - '-para'

```
set code xxx.efi -para
echo %code%
```

Someone could help this orz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some script file like **test.nsh** then put

```
MyUefiApp.efi -some_param
@if not %LastError% == 0 then
    echo [Error] LastError = %LastError%
@else
    echo [OK] Status = 0 [Success]
@endif
```

The point is that, UEFI app can check your status code through system variable LastError.
UEFI Shell Spec 2.2 (It's thanks to my boss. I couldn't find this method before)

Comment: There is no UEFI Shell Specification Version 4.2. You probably mean Version 2.2 which currently is the latest version